# How to remove the style (CSS) from a section of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a CSS framework to make my site look pretty, but one of the drawbacks is that you can't tab to the radio buttons or check boxes.  One of the users has asked for this to be a feature, so, to implement it, I figured I could just remove the styling from that part of the page with a checkbox.

I tested in Chrome, and it doesn't look pretty, but it works.  Now, I still want the navbar, etc, to be styled, and just want this one section to be unstyled, so I can't just disable the styling altogether.

Any ideas?  I've been playing with it, and can't find anything.

Comment: And removing the styling fixes this *how?*  I think you have got the wrong idea somewhere.  Isn't it better to fix the tabbing issue instead?

Comment: @JK. The style removes the elements, and replaces them with other elements.  With no styles in place, the original elements are visible, and tabbing through the form works.  With the style in place, tabbing through the form works for text inputs, but skips right over the checkboxes, because the real checkboxes are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [tab index](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) to your check boxes. there is no need to remove styling.

Comment: you can only select one radio button anyway so tabbing isn't an issue

Comment: you can add a tab index to radio buttons but it will only tab to either the checked one or the first one if none of them are checked

Comment: I have tried to do that, but the way the style is set up, the "actual" elements are moved offscreen, and hidden, and there are some graphics which stand in place.  so tabbing through the form works, and it just skips over the checkboxes section.

Comment: Add your html  and CSS pls

Comment: Or make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zv9xkbnv/

this contains a minimum working example of my HTML, and the entire CSS library from materializecss (the framework i'm using).  I've tried adding tab indexes to both the inputs and the labels (clicking the label activates the checkbox).  no luck

Comment: you're removing the checkbxes. leave them in and jsut style them the way you want